# UITapGesture inside Framework not working

Tags: swift, cocoapods, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer, swift-framework

I'm trying to create my first Cocoapod framework, and need to attach a simple `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a view, but I can't get the tap gesture `action` to be called from within my framework. I've got:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        let foo = Foo()
        foo.attachTo(view: view)
    }
}
```

I created a framework using `pod lib create Foo`, inside is

```
public class Foo {
    public init() {}

    public func attachTo(view: UIView) {
        let endpointGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selected(_:)))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(endpointGesture)
    }

    @objc private func selected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Gesture Recognized")
    }
}
```

I can tell the view is correctly passed into the framework because building the app gives me a blue screen.

Moving the gesture recognizer and `selected` function into `ViewController` works as expected as well. Tapping on the view prints `Gesture Recognized` to the console, so there's something going on with the framework I don't understand.

I have already tried adding the `-ObjC` linker flag to the framework, but that doesn't seem to have done anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: The code you posted looks good, and it appears you know that also. Generally a gesture in a framework is meant to trigger something more than `print` - in my use cases a message to a delegate. Two thoughts: (1) If you set a breakpoint on the `print` statement, does it hit it? (2) If it does, can you either (a) create a protocol/delegate setup to your view controller or (b) refactor (for testing things out) things into a `UIButton` to see what's going on? It really looks like your `print` isn't getting hit.

Comment: Lack of relevant tags...

Comment: @dfd Setting a breakpoint doesn't seem to be doing anything, which leads me to believe the selector is never getting called. I tried creating a protocol/delegate anyways but it didn't call `selected` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `foo` variable is not retained.
If you make the `foo` variable as instance variable it should work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let foo = Foo() // this is now retained by the view controller

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        foo.attachTo(view: view)
    }
}
```